# sending a body in a form of form-data

Tags: ios, objective-c, post, form-data

i have a post request, were i should send a body in the request, but it should be in the form of form-data:
the data are now in an nsmutable dictionary as follow :

```
contacts (
    {
        Images =     (
            "http://otrackapi.omegasoftware.ca/ActStaff/public/uploads/user-image-94.jpg"
        );
        "company_name" = tttt;
        "contact_email" = "tttt@me.com";
        "contact_fname" = tttt;
        "contact_lname" = tttt;
        "contact_phone" = 1323223;
        lat = "37.330434";
        lng = "-122.030163";
        remark = Tttt;
        "type_id" = 18;
    }
)
```

they should be as form-data as below:

```
contants[0][contact_name]: bla
contacts[0][comtact_email]:blabla
```

etc...
if you have postman, you can see it its clearer there, 
any idea how to convert it?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest, try using Alomofire.try to create your JSON and send it to your parameter by a converting it to base64string and tell the Backend guys to decode it then they can get the value.

Answer (score 0):

Try below answer,

```
 // your url 
 NSString *urlString = @"http://www.somesite.com/public/api/v1/create

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

    NSMutableData *body = [NSMutableData data];

    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@", boundary];
   [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
```

Now for adding parameters

```
   // api key parameter: here parameter is 'api' its value is 1
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"api_key\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"1" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    // here parameter is 'subject' and value is taken from '_subjectView.text'
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"subject\"\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[_subjectView.text dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [body appendData:[@"\r\n" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];


    // close form
    [body appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"--%@--\r\n", boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];

    // set request body
    [request setHTTPBody:body];

    // your rest code
```

like this, you can add multiple parameters with value in the body.

If you want to check boundary in postman see below images,

[image]

in postman screen, you may look like this image. In the top right corner, there is one button "Code" click on that button, you will get one pop-up like below image.

check here boundary value.

[image]

Comment: what is the boundary? and where should i add the values? and what is an api key? im usinf afnetworking library

Comment: you can use any random boundary (some predefined boundary ). Have you ever checked in the postman API calls in details?

Comment: at leaset try once, I will share the details