# Server side is not able to read the post body request

Tags: objective-c, afnetworking

[image: image from postman]
I created a post request and I am sending this body as a string to the server :

```
contacts:[
  {
    "company_name" : "rrrr",
    "contact_lname" : "rrrr",
    "remark" : "Fdfdfdfffdfd",
    "Images" : [
      "http:\/\/otrackapi.omegasoftware.ca\/ActStaff\/public\/uploads\/user-image-115.jpg"
    ],
    "type_id" : "24",
    "contact_phone" : "1212233332",
    "lng" : "-122.041202",
    "lat" : "37.337566",
    "contact_email" : "www@test.com",
    "contact_fname" : "rrrr"
  }
]
```

In the following request using AFnetworking:

```
 NSError *error;
     NSData *leadData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:body options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    NSString *leadString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:leadData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSString *leadTest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@",@"contacts:",leadString];
    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[AFHTTPRequestSerializer serializer] requestWithMethod:@"POST" URLString:url parameters:parameters  error:&error];
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = parameters;
    request.timeoutInterval = 30;
    [request setHTTPBody:[leadTest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    AFHTTPSessionManager *manager = [AFHTTPSessionManager manager];
    [[manager dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse * _Nonnull response, id  _Nullable responseObject, NSError * _Nullable error) {
        NSHTTPURLResponse *myResponse = (NSHTTPURLResponse *)response ;
        if (block) {
            block(error, responseObject);
        }else {
            block(responseObject, error);
            return ;

        }
    }]resume];
```

but there is an error, where the server isn't able to read the body, I am receiving the following responseObject:

```
response =     {
        exception = BadRequestException;
        message = "The contacts field is required.";
    };
```

I talked to the backend guys and they told me that the body isn't been read by the server.
Anyone knows whats going around?any help?

UPDATE: I added an image from postman, it works in that way, how to translate it in objective c?
thanks alot

Comment: You don't have to send `{"contacts":[...]}`? I mean not entirely a JSON? Also, why do you send `NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted`?

Comment: because its an array, the contact can contain many objects in it

Comment: I didn't understood your explanation. It doesn't make sense. What you send is not JSON valid, is it okay for your back-end specs?

Comment: its been sent as a string, but in json form. if you have any suggestion to change the form, please paste it

Comment: Your pasted json isn't valid. Missing outer {} and missing quotes around "contacts".

Comment: Why don't you do `NSData *leadData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{"contacts": body} options:0 error:&error];` and then `[request setHTTPBody:leadData];`?

Comment: If you do not have any documentation ask your backend guys to give you an example of how it should work with curl or postman. Once you have a properly working example, paste the curl code here (just don't use the real server name) and we'll see how to convert it to something that will work with AFNetworking (also consider switching to Alamofire).

Comment: i tried this way: NSData *leadData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:@{"contacts": body} options:0 error:&error]; and then [request setHTTPBody:leadData]; but it didnt work also, same responeObject returned

Comment: Then ask your back-end developers for their specs and/or working sample.

Comment: i added an image from postman, please check it

Comment: Note: POSTMAN has a converter into Objective-C, do it, check what's wrong with yours. Points to check: Headers (print request.allHTTPHeaderFields), Body (print `[[NSString alloc] initWithData:[request httpBody] encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]`) from the POSTMan code.

Comment: you posted similar question in this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51632724/sending-a-body-in-a-form-of-form-data/51634589?noredirect=1#comment90233707_51634589. I was  added one solution for it, have you tried????

Comment: according to this example and your JSON response one thing is clear that, you are passing one wrong parameter in API call that is why it is giving response that  contacts field is required. Check the parameter and send throught api call

Comment: yes i have tried it, it didnt work

Answer (score 1):

```
{
"contacts": [{

    "company_name": "rrrr",
    "contact_lname": "rrrr",
    "remark": "Fdfdfdfffdfd",
    "Images": [
        "http:\/\/otrackapi.omegasoftware.ca\/ActStaff\/public\/uploads\/user-image-115.jpg"
    ],
    "type_id": "24",
    "contact_phone": "1212233332",
    "lng": "-122.041202",
    "lat": "37.337566",
    "contact_email": "www@test.com",
    "contact_fname": "rrrr"

}]    }
```

You're JSON is not valid. Try this please.